# In a mysql-django-axios-react setup.... how to update a column in the db using its own value

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, patch, put

Long time listener, first time caller.... learned so much from the forum and its community and many thanks to the platform and the community. Hopefully can get my skills up to contribute.

Have a Mysql - Django - Axios - React setup. I can use Axios PATCH easy enough in react to issue an update through Django RFW to update a column in the db. But I'm stuck on how to update the column using the existing value in the column. For example in db language: table.column1=table.column1+x

I tried a few things like passing a string as the data object but get a 400/bad request/"column requires an integer value" error from django RFW. Rookie mistake with db background...

Last thing I tried was using the django F() expression to construct the data object to pass through axios.patch, and although no errors and get status 200 back from django, nothing happens, no update to the column.

const col = `(column1=F('column1')+${x})`
axios.patch(localhost:8000/Model/${id},col)

When I look at the browser console/network traffic I see FormData that is getting passed from axios to django as:

(column1: F('column1') 9)

/* 9=x */ Which is why I'm guessing nothing happens without the "+"

Obviously I could axios.fetch, update the value, then axios.patch. But trying to avoid the extra trips and also multithread data integrity problems.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.